# bash for loop capable of zero iterations

Tags: bash, for-loop

When iterating through files in a directory as follows

```
for f in *.txt; do
    ...
done
```

the loop will execute one time even if no files matching the specified condition are found. What is the best way to avoid this false entry into the loop? One could place a conditional as the first statement in the loop and trigger a break from the loop if `f` is not defined, but perhaps there is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable the `nullglob` shell setting: `shopt -s nullglob`.

```
$ for f in *.txt; do
    echo "$f"
done
*.txt
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for f in *.txt; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

From the bah man page:

> nullglob
>
> ```
>    If  set,  bash allows patterns which match no files (see
>    Pathname Expansion above) to expand to  a  null  string,
>    rather than themselves.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Is it advisable to reset this shell option after the loop?

Comment: I don't know if there is general wisdom on that but ultimately the question is are things expecting the shell to be in that state. If you are writing the code you can write knowing that you are and deal with it. If you are dealing with other people's code are you going to potentially mess them up? Possibly. Though I can't really think of what that situation would look like.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I wasn't sure if there was some common situation that would end up failing if the shell was left in the `nullglob` state. Probably best to reset to default afterwards unless the modification is taking place in a subshell that won't be used again.

Comment: That's generally my feeling on things. But if someone called me "overly conservative" about this sort of thing it wouldn't surprise me. =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable `nullglob` to make glob not showing `*.txt` when zero `*.txt` files exist:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because, by default, if nothing matches the wildcard `*.txt` then the shell will leave it as `*.txt` rather than null. If you `shopt -s nullglob` then you change this behaviour so that a non-matching wildcard will result in null.

So it's not that `f` is undefined in your loop; it's that it's defined as `*.txt` on its only iteration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out why the shell enters the loop despite the non-existence of files matching the specified criterion.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use `find`:

```
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' | while read f ; do
    echo "$f" 
done
```

The following example can even handle files having newlines in their names (and should therefore be used):

```
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f ; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: As written this is unsafe for files with newlines in their names.

Comment: `-d ''` is equivalent to `-d $'\0'`.